# excel function needs to be updated

Tags: excel, office365

I am running into excel issues, i downloaded an excel and some of the dates are appearing as full dates and some of them are showing Year > Month > Day in the filters which is correct, but the ones which are appearing as full date as: 04/29/2020, but what i am trying is to convert this date to the above format so filters can work properly

I tried evything here, the text to columns, and whatever else on google but none is working.

I tried creating a new column and adding the function to copy the value as date to new column so just hoping that might work.

Here is the function i am trying

```
=DATE(RIGHT(E5,2),MID(E5,3,4),LEFT(E5,2))
```

but the date format is wrong, i am trying to show it as: dd/mm/yyyy

[image]

The red circled ones are wrong

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: here is the attached one https://prnt.sc/1337kew

Comment: the red circled one is wrong

Comment: https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/#:~:text=The%20dates%20in%20Excel%20are%20actually%20stored%20as,like%20DAY%20%28%29%2C%20MONTH%20%28%29%2C%20YEAR%20%28%29%2C%20etc. The point is that once you have a true date you can format its display in whatever way you prefer, whereas while you don't have a true, numeric date you can employ methods to convert your string to a true date. Not knowing which you have leaves you stranded. The link will show you what you should have.

Comment: Your screenshot appears correct. The filter offers the choice of either filtering for all of 2020 or any of the dates. you would get this picture if you have true dates. The formula you tried won't work on true dates because it presumes a string which isn't there. What is it you wish to achieve? When I tried your data the filter was offering me 2020 and Jan, Feb, Mar instead of individual dates.

Comment: @Variatus IMHO the image,indicates the 3 circled items are strings, and the others are dates

Comment: @devee your formula should be `=DATE(RIGHT(E5,4),LEFT(E5,2),MID(E5,4,2))` (you had the parameters in the wrong order, and were extracting the wron characters for Day).  Once you've extractd the date value, you can apply cell format to it as you see fit.

Comment: @devee I'd also check your data on those that are real dates.  It's possible the raw data is in `MM/DD/YYYY` but Excel has assumed `DD/MM/YYYY` (this would be based on your regional settings).  If the raw data could be interpreted either way as a date, eg `01/02/2020`  would be meant to be `2 Jan 2020` but in Excel would be `1 Feb 2020`

Comment: @chris neilsen They should indeed be strings because if they were dates they should be grouped by month as in my test. But they should be dates because they are grouped under "2020", and perhaps there is only one month. I think the point is how Excel sorts the filtered data, by *Value* or *Value2*. I set out to test but then got sidetracked. Perhaps you know.

Comment: @Variatus actually they are not grouped under `2020` (note the `+`.  clicking that would display the month and day groups) adding any arbitary string to the data set would do the same.  The filter list is ordered dates, then numbers, then strings, then boolean, then (Blanks), each block sorted.

Comment: @chris neilsen Thank you. `Value` would filter by "1 Feb 2020" whereas `Value2` would filter for 43832.